# How do I use intellij's code formatter in vscode?

Tags: intellij-idea, visual-studio-code, code-formatting

I'm working on a project that uses Typescript and Java. The code formatting used for the code style is Intellij's default formatting. I am using vscode, so I would like to use Intellij's code formatting in vscode. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: All you can do now is to export EditorConfig file in Settings -> Code Style -> gear icon -> Export, and import this to VSCode. Although this format has many limitations compared to Intellij format

Answer (score 4):

From IntelliJ, export the eclipse formatter file (XML) from settings > editor > Code style > Java
[image]

In Vscode you can download the extension - [Language Support for Java™ by Red Hat](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java) which can import setting from XML files.

In Vscode > user - settings.json add the following

```
"java.format.enabled": true,
"java.format.settings.url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/styleguide/gh-pages/eclipse-java-google-style.xml",
"[java]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "redhat.java"
}
```

you can replace the URL with the local file path or a GitHub XML raw file link (of the previously exported IntelliJ XML file)

for more information on the Vscode extension, you can refer following links

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-linting
- https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/Formatter-settings

However, do note that there still might be differences in formatting between both IDEs (I think it's due to IntelliJ having a separate `IntelliJ code style XML` along with Eclipse XML which overrides some rules).
I prefer to use the [eclipse-java-google-style.xml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/styleguide/gh-pages/eclipse-java-google-style.xml) on both IDEs as it seems more consistent while formatting.